# Floyd-Warshall with negative cycles. How do I find all undefined paths?

Tags: java, shortest-path, floyd-warshall

I have implemented the Floyd Warshall algorithm and it works, but the problem is that I don't know how I can find all paths which are not defined. I have searched around the web but I can only find answers to how to detect if a graph has negative cycles or not.

```
vector< vector <int> > floyd_warshall(vector< vector<int> > d, int n){
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) d[i][i] = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            for(int k = 0; k < n; k++){
                if(d[j][i] + d[i][k] < d[j][k] and d[j][i] != INF and d[i][k] != INF){
                    d[j][k] = d[j][i] + d[i][k];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return d;
}
```

After running the algorithm on the graph:

```
from: to:   weight:
0     1      1
1     2     -1
2     1     -1
1     3      1
4     0      1
```

I get the adjacency matrix:

```
  | 0     1     2     3     4
--|----------------------------
0 | 0    -1    -2    -2     INF
1 | INF  -2    -3    -3     INF
2 | INF  -3    -4    -4     INF
3 | INF   INF   INF   0     INF
4 | 1    -2    -3    -7     0
```

I know that if node i is part of a negative cycle it has a negative value at position d[i][i] in the matrix. So if I check the diagonal of the matrix I can find all nodes which are part of a negative cycle. So if we look in the example above, we can see that node 1 and 2 are parts of a negative cycle. 
The thing is that I want to find which paths that are defined and which that are not defined. If you can come from A to B trough a negative cycle then the length of the path should be undefined since it can be arbitrary small.

So the question is, how can i find all undefined paths?

I want the algorithm to return the matrix: (instead of the one above)

```
  | 0     1     2     3     4
--|----------------------------
0 | 0    -INF   -INF    -INF  INF
1 | INF  -INF   -INF    -INF  INF
2 | INF  -INF   -INF    -INF  INF
3 | INF   INF    INF     0    INF
4 | 1    -INF   -INF    -INF  0
```

Where d[i][j] = INF means that there is no Path between i and j, and -INF means that there's an arbitrary small path between i and j (the path passes a negative loop somewhere) and otherwise is d[i][j] the shortest length between i and j.

I was thinking of test every single path, but that would probably be too slow. There must be some standard way to solve this problem, right?

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well I have found a solution to my own problem.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)    // Go through all possible sources and targets

        for(int k = 0; d[i][j] != -INF && k < n; k++)
            if( d[i][k] != INF && // Is there any path from i to k?
                d[k][j] != INF && // Is there any path from k to j?
                d[k][k] < 0)      // Is k part of a negative loop?

                d[i][j] = -INF;   // If all the above are true
                                  // then the path from i to k is undefined
```

I think it should work and it seems to work too.

Answer (score 4):

I have a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4NQ3HnhyNfQ) that explains exactly how the Floyd-Warshall algorithm works. In essence, the Floyd-Warshall algorithm is used to find the shortest paths between all pairs of nodes in a weighted graph with positive or negative edge weights.

The following algorithm accepts an adjacency matrix, where Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY is used to indicate that two nodes do not connect. For each node, also you'll likely want to initialize a weight of 0 to itself.

This method updates the initial matrix to indicate the minimum distance between all pairs of nodes. If the shortest path is arbitrarily small, then the answer is stored as Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY. If two nodes cannot reach each other then it is still Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY. This implementation runs Floyd Warshall twice and if the path length is smaller than it was before then we are in a negative cycle.

```
static void floydWarshall(double[][] dist) {

  int n = dist.length;

  // Compute shortest paths
  for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        if (dist[i][k] + dist[k][j] < dist[i][j])
          dist[i][j] = dist[i][k] + dist[k][j];

  // Identify negative cycles
  for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        if (dist[i][k] + dist[k][j] < dist[i][j])
          dist[i][j] = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;

}
```

Comment: See my comment on the above answer, this could underflow as well.

Comment: Just to note, the above code doesn't work if a node has an edge with a negative weight to itself because (in some cases) it wouldn't propagate the negative infinity value correctly. See my issue here: https://github.com/williamfiset/Algorithms/issues/260

Answer (score 0):

The Floyd-Warshall algorithm outputs the correct result as long as no negative
cycles exist in the input graph. In case that a negative cycle exists, computing a shortest (simple) path is an NP-hard problem and the
Floyd-Warshall algorithm will not output the correct result.

But it is possible to detect the presence of a negative cycle by checking that there is a negative entry in the diagonal of the matrix. This is done in line 8 and line 9 of this algorithm:

```
1. M[i, j] := ∞ ∀i 6= j
2. M[i, i] := 0 ∀i
3. M[i, j] := c((i, j)) ∀(i, j) ∈ E(G)

4. for i := 1 to n do
5.   for j := 1 to n do
6.     for k := 1 to n do
7.       if M[j, k] > M[j, i] + M[i, k] 
          then M[j, k] := M[j, i] + M[i, k]

8. for i := 1 to n do
9. if M[i, i] < 0 then return(’graph contains a negative cycle’)
```

[Source](http://www.or.uni-bonn.de/~hougardy/paper/Floyd-Warshall.pdf)

Comment: Do we actually need to wait till the end of triple "for" loop to check the diagonal? We could exit as soon as we've found out that the diagonal element became negative after some kth iteration. That's also what is stated in wiki: "should check for negative numbers on the diagonal of the path matrix within the inner for loop of the algorithm"

Comment: This is really bad, if the graph contains a negative cycle the distances could underflow. This condition should be tested in the inner loop of the algorithm. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220110597_The_Floyd-Warshall_algorithm_on_graphs_with_negative_cycles